On page load a button must reflect its database state. How to do?
A page includes buttons that have state. When the page loads, how to query the database during the onLoad event so the actual button state is reflected in the button as drawn?
I expected this to work:
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
function ready(event) {
   document.getElementById(THE_BUTTON).click();
}

Any suggestions welcome.
Ron

you'd make an AJAX call perhaps? or simpler, if the page is dynamically created on the backend.

What do you mean by state on the button? The only state I can think of is enabled/disabled.

where is THE_BUTTON coming from? What database?

All I have is Javascript.

The state is exactly that: enabled or disabled, the point is I need to show that state on the client's page when it is displayed.

THE_BUTTON is the button's ID.
